# How to execute rspec when global constant throws error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have Constant in my gem which will fetch data from consuming application while starting the server. But when I execute test cases How can I skip that calling of constant so that it wont throw any error.

```
#file in my gem
class FallbackConfig
  DATA  = YAML.load(File.open(File.join('config','fallback_data','data.yml')))       
end
```

While running application with gem There is no problem. But when I execute test cases, that time also it is looking for this value and throws following error.

```
Praveen-Mac-mini:global-nav-gem brilliomac$ rspec spec
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/brilliomac/Desktop/global-nav-gem/coverage. 22 / 88 LOC (25.0%) covered.
/Users/brilliomac/Desktop/global-nav-gem/lib/global_nav_gem/configuration_file.rb:2:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/fallback_data/global_nav_data.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this in your test:

```
it 'my test' do
  some_hash = {}
  stub_const(FallbackConfig::DATA, some_hash)
  expect(FallbackConfig::DATA).to eq some_hash
end
```

You can find out more on stubbing the constants with rspec [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants/stub-defined-constant)

Comment: Stubbing will suit when test case executes and throw error.But for me it is executing the above class before executing any testcase and throws error file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the constant to a class method that memoizes the data:

```
class FallbackConfig
  def self.data
    @data ||= YAML.load(...)
  end
end
```

Then change the users of the constant to call the class method instead.  The data will be loaded--just once--if it is used, but not loaded if it is unused.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring you file will immediately call to parsing YAML file, taking away possibility to refine class or redefine constant or anything else. The only solution I see in this situation (but I don't like it) is to temporary redefine `YAML.load` method just before requiring the file and restore it then.

But surely using class method instead of a constant as @wayne-conrad suggests would be far more easier.